# Translation of model properties

Tags: php, mysql, internationalization, filesystems

I am developing an MVC framework (please don't question that, I know..) and currently designing a translation mechanism to maximally ease translation of applications, so far I have a `lang` folder which contains translation files for different pages

```
./lang/en/system.php
./lang/es/system.php
./lang/fr/system.php
```

and so on. Lets say this file contains translations of system messages such as

`./lang/en/system.php`

```
<?php

return array(
    'yourIP' => 'Your IP address is :1'
);
```

To access that in a page I will use a facade class `Lang`, which will fetch the file based on the selected language (stored in session) and give me the translations.

*Controller*

```
public function index() {
    return new View('index', ['translations' => Lang::get('system')]);
}
```

*View*

```
<h1><?= $translations->get('yourIP', System::getClientIP()) ?></h1>
```

This seems to work pretty fast as I can group translations efficiently in separate files for separate modules/pages.

The problem I am trying to solve now is with translating models. For example lets say I'm building a multilingual blog and saving posts in a database. Each post will need translations of its own, but theoretically there can be an unlimited amount of posts. The current method I'm using does not seem very practical.

What I will have to do is create a child directory and store translations like

```
./lang/en/posts/post-1.php
./lang/en/posts/post-2.php
...
./lang/en/posts/post-n.php
```

And that would be for every language, where in this file I will store all translatable (is this a word?) fields of the model and will load it in the model's constructor.

Problems regarding this solution:

- The filesystem will get stuffed with lots of very small files - I'm not really a filesystem expert and I would like to ask if having a large amount of small files like that can cause harm to the filesystem itself including slowdowns of reads and such.
- There will be `n` filesystem reads when retrieving a set of models, where `n` is the number of models. The hard drive is the slowest component in a computer, performing lots of FS reads in a script will present a significant slowdown, now with SSDs maybe not that much but still not a minor problem.

The other solution I came up with is use an additional system database table, which will store translations by table and primary key, something like

```
table INT
model_pk INT
lang INT
translations TEXT
```

where `table` will be a `crc32` encoded number of the name of the table which the translations belong to, `model` will be the PK (id) of the model, `lang` no need to explain and `translations` will be a serialized string containing all translatable properties.

Problems with this approach:

- Forces developer to use a database and obligates them to have a certain table (currently the framework does not require you to have a database and thus there are no system tables when you actually use one).
- models with composite primary keys will not be able to benefit from this since the `model` column can not store a composite key, so only models with a single column primary key will be translatable.

These are just my observations and thoughts, I may be wrong or I may be missing something. I'm posting this question to get advice on which solution will be less problematic from someone with greater experience or propose a completely different one, I'm open to everything.

Comment: Maybe use a local SQLite to hold model translations?

I suppose it doesn't matter too much where its being stored as long as it doesn't force them into running an external server for something (As far as i can see anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build something great first you must understand that what you make until now is called localization (setting app language which will case translation of static data) but you still need to make translation (which mean translate dynamic data like data came from database)

For more details http://content.lionbridge.com/the-difference-between-translation-and-localization-for-multilingual-website-projects-definitions/

For more about localization: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization
and see also https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

For more about translation you can find this package For Laravel Framework interested https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable